# Is this test result right? mmap and write performance test

Tags: java, linux, io, mmap

I did a test about the performance of mmap vs write,read, then I got these real data:

- order write file 100G(file not exist before write)

  - mmap cost 141780ms.
  - read and write cost 127755ms.
- order read file 100G

  - mmap cost 99166ms.
  - read and write cost 80502ms.
- random write 1000w times in a 1G file

  - mmap cost 8844ms.
  - read and write cost 43572ms.
- random read 1000w times in a 1G file

  - mmap cost 7541ms.
  - read and write cost 25199ms.

So I get the following conclusions:

- order read and write: mmap's performance is worse than write,read
- random read and write: mmap's perormance is better than write,read

Is my conclusions right?

---

One of my colleagues said that his impression of mmap is worse than the random read performance of fileChannel.Is my test process correct？

Test environment：32core CPU,96G memory,3T disk(SATA),centOS 6.0

My test code:

```
public class Main {
public static void mmap_random_write() throws Exception{
    Random random = new Random() ;
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt" , "rw") ;
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4); //4K buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
    MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
    for(int i=0 ; i<1000*10000 ; i++){
        byteBuffer.flip();
        int offset = random.nextInt(size - 4*1024) ;
        mappedByteBuffer.position(offset) ;
        mappedByteBuffer.put(byteBuffer) ;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ": mmap random write") ;

    fileChannel.close();
}

public static void mmap_random_read() throws Exception{
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt" , "rw") ;
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4*1024] ;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
    MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
    Random random = new Random() ;
    for(long i=0 ; i<1000*10000; i++){
        int offset = random.nextInt(size - 4*1024) ;
        mappedByteBuffer.position(offset) ;
        mappedByteBuffer.get(bytes) ;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ": mmap random read");

    fileChannel.close();
}

public static void mmap_order_read() throws Exception{
    FileChannel[] fileChannels = new FileChannel[100] ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file" + i + ".txt" , "rw") ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;
        fileChannels[i] = fileChannel ;
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4*1024] ;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<fileChannels.length ; i++){
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileChannels[i] ;
        MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
        int writeCount = size / (4 * 1024);
        for (int count = 0; count < writeCount; count++) {
            byteBuffer.flip();
            mappedByteBuffer.get(bytes) ;
        }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":mmap order read");


    for(FileChannel fileChannel : fileChannels){
        fileChannel.close();
    }
}

public static void mmap_order_write() throws Exception{
    FileChannel[] fileChannels = new FileChannel[100] ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("mmap" + i + ".txt" , "rw") ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;
        fileChannels[i] = fileChannel ;
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<fileChannels.length ; i++){
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileChannels[i] ;
        MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
        int writeCount = size / (4 * 1024);
        for (int count = 0; count < writeCount; count++) {
            byteBuffer.flip();
            mappedByteBuffer.put(byteBuffer) ;
        }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":mmap order write");


    for(FileChannel fileChannel : fileChannels){
        fileChannel.close();
    }
}

public static void channel_order_write() throws Exception {
    FileChannel[] fileChannels = new FileChannel[100] ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("fileChannel" + i + ".txt" , "rw") ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;
        fileChannels[i] = fileChannel ;
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<fileChannels.length ; i++){
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileChannels[i] ;
        int writeCount = size / (4 * 1024);
        for (int count = 0; count < writeCount; count++) {
            byteBuffer.flip();
            fileChannel.write(byteBuffer) ;
        }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":read() and write() order write");


    for(FileChannel fileChannel : fileChannels){
        fileChannel.close();
    }
}

public static void channel_order_read() throws Exception{
    FileChannel[] fileChannels = new FileChannel[100] ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file" + i + ".txt" , "rw") ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;
        fileChannels[i] = fileChannel ;
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<fileChannels.length ; i++){
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileChannels[i] ;
        int writeCount = size / (4 * 1024);
        for (int count = 0; count < writeCount; count++) {
            byteBuffer.rewind();
            fileChannel.read(byteBuffer) ;
        }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":read() and write() order read");


    for(FileChannel fileChannel : fileChannels){
        fileChannel.close();
    }
}

public static void channel_random_read()throws Exception{
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt" , "rw") ;
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
    Random random = new Random() ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<1000*10000 ; i++){
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        int offset = random.nextInt(size - 4*1024) ;
        fileChannel.position(offset) ;
        fileChannel.read(byteBuffer) ;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":read() and write() random read");

    fileChannel.close();
}

public static void channel_random_write()throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random() ;
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt" , "rw") ;
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel() ;

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 4; i++) {
        byteBuffer.put((byte) 1);
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime() ;
    int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;
    for(int i=0 ; i<1000*10000 ; i++){
        byteBuffer.flip();
        int offset = random.nextInt(size - 4*1024) ;
        fileChannel.position(offset) ;
        fileChannel.write(byteBuffer) ;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println((end - start) + ":read() and write() random write");

    fileChannel.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you format these large numbers to be human readable? Why using nanoseconds when a better scale would be better to comprehend?

Comment: or at least right justify and add a decimal separator (`.` or `,` as is your local convention). But.. Better that average testing Q. Good luck.

Comment: The propose of using nanoseconds is to hava a more precise time, and prevent the effect of time drift

Comment: Note that `mmap()`'ing files via byte buffers in Java is somewhat problematic - there's no safe way to reliably unmap them on demand.  See https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724038 That's been around since 2002, and it **may** get fixed in Java 10 as fixing it requires a change to the JVM memory model. So when you're dealing with huge files, you potentially can have some serious memory problems.